# Kubuntu vs KDE Plasma on Ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, distro-recommendation

I am a relatively new Linux user who has been running Mint on a 2018 Aero 15x laptop for a few months now. Everything works well enough, but I've had miscellaneous compatibility issues and I have heard that Ubuntu has the best hardware support for newer laptops and I am strongly considering switching over. I also really like the look and customizability of Plasma, so would definitely prefer using it over GNOME, but I have a few questions about the differences between **KDE Neon**, **Kubuntu**, and **Ubuntu running KDE Plasma**.

I know what each of them are, but I was curious if Neon and Kubuntu have the same hardware compatibility as Ubuntu/if there is any advantage to running Ubuntu with plasma over either of the options with plasma baked in. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the advice! My question is primarily about Ubuntu and Kubuntu -- which are both official flavors -- although I will keep this in mind for future questions on different distros.